# Common lisp libset closest to clojure's core.async

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

What would be the correct libset and approach to achieve the behavour alike that of clojure's [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) in common lisp? Namely parkable coroutines in combination with communitation over parking (non thread-blocking) channels.

Taking a look at [calispel](https://github.com/hawkir/calispel), [chanl](https://github.com/zkat/chanl) and [cl-coroutine](https://github.com/takagi/cl-coroutine) but can't get how to achieve it. Is it even possible, or i should use some kind of java approach with thread pools / futures + channels (blocking queues?) ?

Answer (score 4):

This looks a bit like [lparallel](https://lparallel.org), at least that there is a thread-pool and 'go blocks' are executed in that pool where within the block the operations like <! >! do block.

Comment: Thanks! That looks good. Though i can't find any facility for `select / alt` over multiple queues anywhere in it's docs. Pretty sure there's none. How would you achieve this functionality in lparallel ?

Comment: Not entirely certain. But you could setup multiple 'channels'. AFAIR 'channels' in lparallel are kind of a queue between caller and worker.